# javascript how to form an array of objects by combining first Array and their values are in other arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im facing a small issue in Javascript.

I have below Arrays.

```
var labels = ["labelOne", "labelTwo"];
var values1 = ["89", "9"];
var values2 = ["32", "78"];
```

**Here we can place n number of values arrays like value3,value4....**

Now how can i form an array of Objects by combining `labels` Array and their values are in `values` arrays. Im expecting the below output after combining above 3 arrays..

```
var mainArray = [{
label:"labelOne",
value:"89"
},
{
label:"labelTwo",
value:"9"
},
{
label:"labelOne",
value:"32"
},
{
label:"labelTwo",
value:"78"
}]
```

Can someone please help me to achieve the above output.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic variable names. If you have `values1`, `values2`, etc. they should just be a single array `var values = [[...], [...], [...], ...]`

Comment: If you do that, you will be able to use nested loops to solve your problem.

Comment: @Barmar Here all Arrays will be coming dynamically as a response from backend. So how can i make only values in Single array?

Comment: If they're coming from a response from the backend, how are you putting them into different variables in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is a variable to know how many arrays should be added and access them in a loop using the advantage that Javascript lets you get them like this: `window['variableName']` when they are defined in global scope.

```js
var labels = ["labelOne", "labelTwo"];
var values1 = ["89", "9"];
var values2 = ["32", "78"];
var mainArray = [];

// Define a variable to know how many arrays should be added
var maxValues = 2;

function addValues(values) {
  // Create new elements and push them into mainArray
  mainArray.push({label:labels[0], value:values[0]});
  mainArray.push({label:labels[1], value:values[1]});
}

// Do a loop from 1 to maxValues
for(let i = 1; i <= maxValues; i++) {
    // Call the function with dynamic variable name
    addValues(window['values' + i]);
}

console.log(mainArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of your array isn't critical (and then, you might sort it later if it is), you can do like this:

```
const output = labels.map((label, index) => {
    return [{ label, value: values1[index] }, { label, value: values2[index] }];
}).flat();
```

The `map` step, will give you an array like this:

```
[
    [{ label: 'labelOne', value: 89 }, { label: 'labelOne', value: 32 }],
    [{ label: 'labelTwo', value: 9}, { label: 'labelTwo', value: 78}]
]
```

By then calling `flat`, it'll transform it into:

```
[{ label: 'labelOne', value: 89 }, { label: 'labelOne', value: 32 }, { label: 'labelTwo', value: 9}, { label: 'labelTwo', value: 78}]
```

Which is what you wanted, from here you can sort the array if that matters for your use case.